# Ошибка при создании роли через слеш команду

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Делаю так что бы в slash команде вводил название и цвет роли и она создавалась

```
from discord_slash import SlashCommand

@slash.slash(name="role", description="Команда для покупки кастомной роли")
async def create_role(ctx, name, color: discord.Colour):
    guild = ctx.guild
    print(name)
    print(color)
    role = await guild.create_role(name=name, colour=color)
    user = ctx.author
    await user.add_roles(role)
    embed = discord.Embed (
        color = 0xff3d3d,
        description = (f'роль **{name}**, с цветом **{color}**, успешно создана'))
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Команду запросил {ctx.author}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Но выдает ошибку

```
An exception has occurred while executing command `role`:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bobr_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 1353, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "C:\Users\bobr_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\model.py", line 210, in invoke
    return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/bobr_/Desktop/Discord Bot/discord_bot.py", line 123, in create_role
    role = await guild.create_role(name=name, colour=color)
  File "C:\Users\bobr_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\guild.py", line 1894, in create_role
    fields['color'] = colour.value
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'
```

Помогите!

Comment: Приложите полный текст ошибки

Comment: Приложил ошибку

Comment: Вот здесь вы хотите заставить `discord` преобразовать строку в цвет. Как конкретно вы хотите, чтобы это произошло? Какое значение вы передаете в качестве цвета?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я без понятия, что вы передаете в команду в качестве параметра цвета, но, дискорд, судя по всему, не знает как превратить переданную вами строку в цвет.

Как вариант, можно принимать цвет в формате `HEX`, то есть `#******`.

В документации к [`discord.Colour`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=colour#colour) я почему-то не нашел метода для получения цвета из `HEX`-формата, поэтому придется делать все руками.

В формате `HEX` каждые 2 символа после решетки обозначают число от `0` до `255` в шестнадцатеричной системе исчисления. Это значит, что, например, `FF` можно преобразовать через `int('FF', 16)` к числу `255` и другие символы тоже.

Значит достаточно просто написать функцию, которая будет преобразовывать указанную строку в кортеж из трех значений от `0` до `255`, то есть значения `RGB`, из которых уже можно получить цвет методом `discord.Colour.from_rgb(r, g, b)`:

```py
def colour_from_hex(value):
    value = value.lstrip('#')
    lv = len(value)
    return discord.Colour.from_rgb(*tuple(int(value[i:i + lv // 3], 16) for i in range(0, lv, lv // 3)))
```

А затем просто преобразуем `HEX`-строку к цвету.

```
@slash.slash(name='test')
async def __test(ctx, color):
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=color, color=colour_from_hex(color)))
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ,  у меня все заработало! Вы меня спасаете уже второй раз!